# Draggable divs stacking not working (no framework used)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm crafting a "Playlist" style interface, where you can drag and drop elements back and forth from each playlist. Each element is a div (no ul methods needed so far). I'm using core draggable JS code, everything works fine til I start playing with them a bit more:

a) If I drag element 1 below or above element 2 (within the same container or not), instead of pushing the element 2 upwards or downwards, it actually inserts my dragged element1 into element 2 (sometimes it even disappears), ending up with a 2 element included draggable div.

c) If i drag element X to any empty container or a populated one but with enough free space below the actual content, it works properly, but when I try it again moving it to the top container area, or try to arrange any given between others, it gets inserted again into the element listed closer to the dropped spot.

Any ideas on how to avoid this? All of this is random as you can see, sometimes it stacks properly, sometimes it doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.mycontainer {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
.myelement {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="mycontainer">
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" class="myelement">ELEMENT 1</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" class="myelement">ELEMENT 2</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" class="myelement">ELEMENT 3</div>
</div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="mycontainer"></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/sLkxs2j3/ ?

Comment: wow! almost there mate! problem is that I need to let the user rearrange the order of the divs as wanted, with this example we fix the initial bug but I loose the free rearrange feature, they stay put where they landed :/ BUT IT IS AN AMAZING approach, thanks indeed.

Comment: We can arrange the order with this approach too...Try it out...

Comment: Just double checked, and indeed is still doable, thanks mate. Almost impossible to arrange them dragging elements upwards (within the same container) though! but this is just perfect for the prototype. Appreciate it!